# Cassandra -- nodetool is not working on another machine?

Tags: java, cassandra

I have a cassandra cluster on 4 nodes (each running ubuntu 10.04 and cassandra 0.7.4).
All nodes are connected using a SWITCH, and each is assigned a STATIC IP ADDRESS (no DNS is involved).

The node seems to be functioning properly (status is 'Normal', all nodes are up etc).

The problem is this: `nodetool` works, yet it only works when the `nodetool` command is run on the same node. When I try to run `nodetool` from **STATIC_IP = 192.168.0.253** on **STATIC_IP = 192.168.0.4** I get the following error:

(note: machine 's3789' has the static IP of 192.168.0.253)

`user@s3789:/opt/cassandra/apache-cassandra-0.7.4$      bin/nodetool -host 192.168.0.4 ring`

`Error connection to remote JMX agent!
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:128)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl_Stub.newClient(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.getConnection(RMIConnector.java:2343)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:296)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:267)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeProbe.connect(NodeProbe.java:137)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeProbe.<init>(NodeProbe.java:107)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeCmd.main(NodeCmd.java:511)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:193)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:384)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:495)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:206)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)`

Any hints how to solve this?

Comment: *Educated guess:* have you put the specified ip address and port to a `hosts` allow file?

Comment: There is no `hosts` deny file, why should I use the `allow`?

Comment: some do...but if you have `hosts` file, why not include your ip addresses there?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

from conf/cassandra-env.sh:

```sh
# add this if you're having trouble connecting:
# JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<public name>"
# 
# see 
# https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/troubleshooting_connection_problems_in_jconsole
# for more on configuring JMX through firewalls, etc. (Short version:
# get it working with no firewall first.)
```

Comment: thank you. I wish there was a good & easy to understand documentation -- I've been spending hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: I had the same problem as the original poster. This fix helped but I also needed to open ports on the internal LAN firewall so that the cassandra nodes could communicate. So make sure all the ports needed by cassandra are open.

Comment: @jbellis:yes worked... but I didnt get that how did that work in MAC OS without adding 
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<public name> 
at the end..?
might be it is JVM related?can you explain it properly

Comment: @user3262424 ! what exactly did you pass in <public name> filed. is the public ip??

Answer (score 0):

Check if you started rmiregistry before starting the server

```
rmiregistry &
```

[Getting started with RMI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html#5)